# Vim: Underline content of \underline{} in (La)TeX files

Tags: vim, latex, vim-plugin, tex

When I'm editing (La)TeX files, Vim (with the default colorscheme) uses a bold font for the contents of `\textbf{}`, inverts the background color of `\textit{}`'s contents, etc.

I would like it to also underline the contents of `\underline{}`.

I've come up with a rather hacky solution that works in most cases, but breaks when the `\underline{}` contains a closing brace `}`:

```
highlight underline term=underline cterm=underline gui=underline
match underline /\\underline{\zs.\{-}\ze}/
```

<sub>(The `underline` highlight definition is necessary because `Underlined` changes the color of the text.)</sub>

How can I do this more elegantly?
I've looked at `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/tex.vim`, but I can't seem to adapt something like `syn region texBoldStyle matchgroup=texTypeStyle start="\\textbf\s*{" end="}" concealends contains=@texBoldGroup` to my needs…

Comment: By the way, I'm not entirely sure if this is considered on topic for *Stack Overflow*, but *SO* has 13527 questions tagged [vim], compared to 2386 on *Super User*, 626 on *Unix & Linux* and 145 on *TeX — LaTeX*.

Answer (score 1):

Place the cursor over `\underline{foo}` and type that command:

```
:echo map(synstack(line('.'), col('.')), 'synIDattr(v:val, "name")')
```

It will tell you which highlight group is used for that symbol. Once you have that information, you can try to add your `highlight` line to:

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim
```

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem is `\}` inside the `\underline{}`, then here's an improved regex:

```
/\\underline{\zs\(.\([^\\]}\)\@<!\)\+\ze}/
```

Alternatively, it is indeed possible to properly add it to `syntax/tex.vim`: add a `syn cluster texUnderlineGroup` (and add it under `contains=` for all appropriate existing clusters), add a `syn region texUnderlineStyle`, and finally add a `hi texUnderlineStyle`.